# USB not working on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, usb-drive, fdisk, usb-device, camera

The USB ports in my notebook don't work for my kindle and my pendriver. Although they work with my cellphone. I tried running `fdisk -l` and all the sdb partitions are missing. But if I run `lsusb` the device appears. The ports work normally on Debian. Also my webcam doesn't appear to be working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I had a newer version of the linux kernel installed that didn't had some modules. So I just returned to a previous version through my dual boot menu and it fixed it.